# Parsing bson.M with mgo in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am looking to parse specific values out of MongoDB diagnostic commands using the mgo connector. I can loop through the bson.M{} response, but I'm unsure how to actually pull out specific nested values within the map and store them as a value. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
    //Connect to mongo shell
session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

//Get connPoolStats
connResult := bson.M{}
if err := session.DB("admin").Run("connPoolStats", &connResult); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    for key, value := range connResult {
        fmt.Println(key, value)
}
```

The output is:

```
totalRefreshing 0
hosts map[]
replicaSets map[]
numClientConnections 0
totalInUse 0
totalAvailable 0
totalCreated 0
numAScopedConnections 0
pools map[]
ok 1
```

I would like to pull out numClientConnections, totalInUse, available, etc and store them in variables-- as well as pull out values from the nested maps within `pools map[]` Do I need to convert to json to do this or use something other than bson.M?

Comment: You can use `bson.M`, it's just a `map[string]interface{}`: https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M

Comment: What's the correct syntax to parse a value out? I can't really find good documentation/examples on the matter-- I've tried `value.numClientConnections`

Comment: It's already been parsed, and you access it like any other `map`: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19 e.g. `value["numClientConnections"]`

Comment: Tried that as well, but I get an error such as `invalid operation: value["numClientConnections"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`

Comment: Sorry, I was basing that comment on your comment, not on the code in your question. It would be `connResult["numClientConnections"]`.